# How to successfully exclude JBoss EAP 6.1 packed libraries such as Resteasy from my deployment?

Tags: java, jersey, resteasy, jboss6.x

I used to deploy to JBoss 5.1.0.GA but I was required to move my project to JBoss 6.1.0.Final.

After changing the server in my project, I can't deploy my project anymore, I get many warnings and at the end an error, the following is the stack trace for this error:

```
22:05:20,628 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PreReal: name=vfs:///E:/Users/B274040/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_AS_6.x1426130613068/deploy/AcertumCreditCardAuthorizationService.war state=PostClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PreReal: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed. com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig
    at org.jboss.resteasy.integration.deployers.ResteasyScannerDeployer.scan(ResteasyScannerDeployer.java:175) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.integration.deployers.ResteasyScannerDeployer.internalDeploy(ResteasyScannerDeployer.java:64) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1454) [:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:74) [:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1295) [:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1387) [:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:818) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_45]
```

From this error we get the line:

> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Only one JAX-RS
>   Application Class allowed.

After doing some search around I found out this error happens because my project uses libraries that JBoss includes, in this case the problem lies with Resteasy in JBoss conflicting with my Jersey libraries.

I don't want to use the Resteasy libraries at all, the ones that come with JBoss are older verions and upgrading them will only work on my workstation, the production server specifications are unknown to us and every project to be run there must be responsable of the libraries they use.

I tried to include a jboss-deploymen-structure.xml, in both META-INF and WEB-INF:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.jackson-provider"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider"/>
           <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider"/>
           <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl"/>
           <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-jaxrs"/>
           <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl"/>
           <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-xc"/>
           <module name="org.codehaus.jettison"/>
           <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
           <module name="javaee.api"/>
        </exclusions>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="resteasy" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

However this didn't work at all.

How can I exclude these libraries?

Comment: oh jBoss... I remember when I was working with java and we switched from web logic to jboss... have a look at my answer here, I had a similar problem in the past. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087782/jboss-not-using-logback-for-logging basically if you're deploying an ear with a bunch of jars in it, you have to specify every jar as a sub deployment I think

Comment: I'm deploying a war file, does it work for it too?

Comment: Yea I believe so. Does the war have jars in it? If so just declare each jar as a sub deployment. I think wars and ears are equivalent in that they are just a kind of compressed or zipped file so this should function the same way for both