# Can't deploy a jar on Jboss EAP6 with error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I try to deploy a maven projet (jar) on Jboss EAP6 but at every time it gives me the errors bellow:

```
`17:55:58,212 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."services-1.0.0.ear"."services-trans-1.0.1.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."services-1.0.0.ear"."services-tran-1.0.1.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: N'a pas pu traiter la phase POST_MODULE de subdeployment "services-tran-1.0.1.jar" of deployment "services-1.0.0.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]`
`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Erreur d'obtention d'informations réflectives pour class services.tran.impl.BrTranFactory pour le ClassLoader (Chargeur de classe) ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.services-1.0.0.ear.services-tran-1.0.1.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]`
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Linterfaces/br/locals/IBrFactoryLocal;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]`
```

Comment: have you created the jboss deployment structure correctly? take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087782/jboss-not-using-logback-for-logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 3 projects .jar which are included in a ear project thus I found that one of these projects does not deploy alone on the server Jboss and that the other projects depend on that there, it is for that that gives this error message.